# Bad results in sparse matrix assignment with logical indexing

Tags: julia

In Matlab/Octave, I can use logical indexing to assign a value to matrix B in every location that meets a certain requirement in matrix A.

```
octave:1> A = [.1;.2;.3;.4;.11;.13;.14;.01;.04;.09];
octave:2> C = A < .12
C =

   1
   0
   0
   0
   1
   0
   0
   1
   1
   1

octave:3> B = spalloc(10,1);
octave:4> B(C) = 1
B =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 10, cols = 1, nnz = 5 [50%])

  (1, 1) ->  1
  (5, 1) ->  1
  (8, 1) ->  1
  (9, 1) ->  1
  (10, 1) ->  1
```

However, if I attempt essentially the same code in Julia, the results are incorrect:

```
julia> A = [.1;.2;.3;.4;.11;.13;.14;.01;.04;.09];

julia> B = spzeros(10,1)
10x1 sparse matrix with 0 Float64 entries:

julia> C = A .< .12
10-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
 false
 false
  true
 false
 false
  true
  true
  true

julia> B[C] = 1
1

julia> B
10x1 sparse matrix with 5 Float64 entries:
    [0 ,  1]  =  1.0
    [0 ,  1]  =  1.0
    [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
    [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
    [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
```

Have I made a mistake in the syntax somewhere, am I misunderstanding something, or is this a bug? Note, I get the correct results if I use full matrices in Julia, but since the matrix in my application is really sparse (essential boundary conditions in a finite element simulation), I would much prefer to use the sparse matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if `sparse` has some problems with `BitArray`'s.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.3.5"
julia> A = [.1;.2;.3;.4;.11;.13;.14;.01;.04;.09]
julia> B = spzeros(10,1)
julia> C = A .< .12
julia> B[C] = 1
julia> B
10x1 sparse matrix with 5 Float64 entries:
        [0 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [0 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
```

So I get the same thing as the questioner.  However when I do things "my way"

```
julia> B = sparse(C)
ERROR: `sparse` has no method matching sparse(::BitArray{1})

julia> B = sparse(float(C))
10x1 sparse matrix with 5 Float64 entries:
        [1 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [5 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [8 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [9 ,  1]  =  1.0
        [10,  1]  =  1.0
```

So this works if you convert the `BitArray` to `Float`. I imagine that this workaround will get you going, but it does seem that `sparse` should work with `BitArray`.

**Some Additional Thoughts (Edit)**

As I thought further about this, it occurs to me that one reason why there is no `BitArray` method for `sparse()` is that it is not terribly useful to implement sparse storage for an already highly compact type.  Considering `B` and `C` from above:

```
julia> sizeof(C)
8

julia> sizeof(B)
40
```

So for these data, the `sparse` version is much larger than the original.  It's actually worse than this simple (perhaps simplistic) check shows at first glance.  `sizeof(::BitArray{1})` appears to be the size of the entire array, but `sizeof(::SparseMatrixCSC{})` shows the size of each element stored.  So the real size disparity is something like 8 versus 200 bytes.

Of course if the data is sparse enough (somewhat less than 1% `true`), sparse storage begins to win out, despite it's high overhead.

```
julia> C = rand(10^6) .< 0.01

julia> B = sparse(float(C))

julia> sizeof(C)
125000

julia> sum(C)*sizeof(B)
394520

julia> C = rand(10^6) .< 0.001

julia> B = sparse(float(C))

julia> sizeof(C)
125000

julia> sum(C)*sizeof(B)
40280
```

So perhaps it is not an oversight that `sparse()` has no `BitArray` method.  Cases where it would represent a significant space saving may be less common than one might think at first glance.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. And here I was blindly converting Matlab code into Julia code...